# Need JavaScript help for smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor

I have a working "go to top" button in my forum. I have chosen to go with the following code because it does not change my forum's URL in any way, which is important. Within the `head` section:

```
<script>
  function scrollWindow() {
    var top = document.getElementById('goHere').scrollTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }
</script>
```

The div within the body I want to go to:

```
<div id="goHere"></div>
```

The input:

```
<input type="image" onclick="scrollWindow()" value="Scroll" class="goTop" src="http://example.com/images/26.png" alt="" />
```

It functions well and leaves my URL clean. My questions:

1. Can my JavaScript be edited to allow smooth scrolling to the `div` ID (and if so, would you please help me with the edits)?
2. Must I link to an external jQuery file in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So making it as simple as possible, here it is using JQuery, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aq9ptz0L/2/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#goHere").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Note in your `<head>` section add this if you dont already have JQuery:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Wow, that's great!  Works beautifully and my PHP is happy with it.  Thanks so much!  And thanks, SaiKiran, for your work, as well.  :)

Comment: Is that possible to I apply that smooth scrolling the the whole of my website? I mean when user turns his mouse's scroll-button *(or anyway changing scroll-bar of the page)*, I want a smooth scrolling.

Comment: Yes kind of,but it would be an entirly different approach though

Comment: Ah I see. well maybe I ask a new question later.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script instead of your script and working fiddle here [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/uppusaikiran/42aasf65/2/)

```
!function(e,t){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(t):"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t():e.smoothScroll=t()}(this,function(){"use strict";if("object"==typeof window&&void 0!==document.querySelectorAll&&void 0!==window.pageYOffset&&void 0!==history.pushState){var e=function(e){return"HTML"===e.nodeName?-window.pageYOffset:e.getBoundingClientRect().top+window.pageYOffset},t=function(e){return.5>e?4*e*e*e:(e-1)*(2*e-2)*(2*e-2)+1},n=function(e,n,o,i){return o>i?n:e+(n-e)*t(o/i)},o=function(t,o,i,r){o=o||500,r=r||window;var u=window.pageYOffset;if("number"==typeof t)var a=parseInt(t);else var a=e(t);var d=Date.now(),f=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||function(e){window.setTimeout(e,15)},s=function(){var e=Date.now()-d;r!==window?r.scrollTop=n(u,a,e,o):window.scroll(0,n(u,a,e,o)),e>o?"function"==typeof i&&i(t):f(s)};s()},i=function(e){e.preventDefault(),location.hash!==this.hash&&window.history.pushState(null,null,this.hash),o(document.getElementById(this.hash.substring(1)),500,function(e){location.replace("#"+e.id)})};return document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){for(var e,t=document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])'),n=t.length;e=t[--n];)e.addEventListener("click",i,!1)}),o}});

function scrollWindow() {
    var top = document.getElementById('goHere');
    window.smoothScroll(top)
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm in the process of testing your script.  However, I forgot to mention that my file is PHP, so I'm having to work out back-slashing some of the quotes in order to get my page back.

Comment: "Can my JS be edited to allow smooth scrolling to the div ID" - your code scrolls to the top, not to the `<div id="goHere"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for that; I'll try again.  It was caught in an echo statement in the head (which is where my original JS is, so the quotes were breaking the page.

Comment: The fiddle works beautifully.  The problem I'm having is that I must capture the script within a PHP echo statement and once I backslash the quotes I get my page to render again, but it seems to break function.